# Why progress bar is displaying differently for same value?

Tags: html, css

I am working on circular progress bar using HTML & CSS.  HTML content is under for loop. Here, I tried with same `5%` but the result of progress is different

```css
   .progress{
        width: 120px;
        height: 120px;
        line-height: 120px;
        background: none;
        margin: 0 auto;
        box-shadow: none;
        position: relative;
    }
    .progress:after{
        content: "";
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        border-radius: 50%;
        border: 15px solid #f2f5f5;
        position: absolute;
        top: 0;
        left: 0;
    }
    .progress > span{
        width: 50%;
        height: 100%;
        overflow: hidden;
        position: absolute;
        top: 0;
        z-index: 1;
    }
    .progress .progress-left{
        left: 0;
    }
    .progress .progress-bar{
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        background: none;
        border-width: 12px;
        border-style: solid;
        position: absolute;
        top: 0;
    }
    .progress .progress-left .progress-bar{
        left: 100%;
        border-top-right-radius: 80px;
        border-bottom-right-radius: 80px;
        border-left: 0;
        -webkit-transform-origin: center left;
        transform-origin: center left;
    }
    .progress .progress-right{
        right: 0;
    }
    .progress .progress-right .progress-bar{
        left: -100%;
        border-top-left-radius: 80px;
        border-bottom-left-radius: 80px;
        border-right: 0;
        -webkit-transform-origin: center right;
        transform-origin: center right;
        animation: loading-1 1.8s linear forwards;
    }
    .progress .progress-value{
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        font-size: 14px;
        font-weight: bold;
        text-align: center;
        position: absolute;
    }
    .progress .progress-value.red {
        color: #f74d4d;
    }
    .progress .progress-value.dark-yellow {
        color: #f78c4d;
    }
    .progress .progress-value.yellow {
        color: #f7f24d;
    }
    .progress .progress-value.green {
        color: #28b779;
    }
    .progress.red .progress-bar{
        border-color: #f74d4d;
    }
    .progress.red .progress-left .progress-bar{
        animation: loading-2 1.5s linear forwards 1.8s;
    }
    .progress.dark-yellow .progress-bar{
        border-color: #f78c4d;
    }
    .progress.dark-yellow .progress-left .progress-bar{
        animation: loading-4 0.4s linear forwards 1.8s;
    }
    .progress.yellow .progress-bar{
        border-color:#f7f24d;
    }
    .progress.yellow .progress-left .progress-bar{
        animation: loading-3 1s linear forwards 1.8s;
    }
    .progress.green .progress-bar{
        border-color: #28b779;
    }
    .progress.green .progress-left .progress-bar{
        animation: loading-5 1.2s linear forwards 1.8s;
    }
    .progress > span {
        background-color: none;
    }
    @keyframes loading-1{
        0%{
            -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
            transform: rotate(0deg);
        }
        100%{
            -webkit-transform: rotate(180deg);
            transform: rotate(180deg);
        }
    }
    @keyframes loading-2{
        0%{
            -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
            transform: rotate(0deg);
        }
        100%{
            -webkit-transform: rotate(144deg);
            transform: rotate(144deg);
        }
    }
    @keyframes loading-3{
        0%{
            -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
            transform: rotate(0deg);
        }
        100%{
            -webkit-transform: rotate(90deg);
            transform: rotate(90deg);
        }
    }
    @keyframes loading-4{
        0%{
            -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
            transform: rotate(0deg);
        }
        100%{
            -webkit-transform: rotate(36deg);
            transform: rotate(36deg);
        }
    }
    @keyframes loading-5{
        0%{
            -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
            transform: rotate(0deg);
        }
        100%{
            -webkit-transform: rotate(126deg);
            transform: rotate(126deg);
        }
    }
    @media only screen and (max-width: 990px){
        .progress{ margin-bottom: 20px; }
    }
```

```html
<div class="component-progress-info">
    <div class="component-progress">
        <div class="progress <?php echo $componentclass; ?>">
            <span class="progress-left">
                <span class="progress-bar"></span>
            </span>
            <span class="progress-right">
                <span class="progress-bar"></span>
            </span>
            <div class="progress-value red">5%</div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="component-info">
        
    </div>
</div>
```

I have html inside a `for-loop`. But it is resulting me different response

[image: error]

Comment: @Mani yes I have hard coded `5%` But the progress bar doesnot look like (5%) and each case its different

Comment: Please post the resultant HTML source codes (not the codes with PHP).

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the CSS (just the relevant parts):

```css
.progress.red .progress-left .progress-bar{
  animation: loading-2 1.5s linear forwards 1.8s;
}
.progress.dark-yellow .progress-left .progress-bar{
  animation: loading-4 0.4s linear forwards 1.8s;
}
.progress.yellow .progress-left .progress-bar{
  animation: loading-3 1s linear forwards 1.8s;
}
.progress.green .progress-left .progress-bar{
  animation: loading-5 1.2s linear forwards 1.8s;
}
```

Different colors are set to use different keyframes, for example `loading-3` for yellow, `loading-5` for green, as seen above.

The keyframes then are defined with different rotations. Looking at two of them as an example:

```css
@keyframes loading-2{
  0%{
    -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
    transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  100%{
    -webkit-transform: rotate(144deg);
    transform: rotate(144deg);
  }
}
@keyframes loading-3{
  0%{
    -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
    transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  100%{
    -webkit-transform: rotate(90deg);
    transform: rotate(90deg);
  }
}
```

Here `loading-2` transforms from 0deg to 144deg.
Below `loading-3` transforms from 0deg to 90deg.

Should the keyframes not be the same for every progress bar? Only the background color should change. But you define different keyframes for different colors, which is probably the cause if not part of it.